# DCM4CHEE function description

Tags: java, dcm4che

There is class named `DcmQR`. I need to download the images from the dcm4chee server for that I need to use the function `addStoreTransferCapability`. This function needs two arguments `cuid` , and `tsuid` with data type string what are these arguments can anyone please explain. The coding is being done in java.

Answer (score 0):

I get the answer for this:
tsuid is Transfer syntax UID and csuid is Class SOP uid.